# How to set vehicel take a lanechange constantly instead of instantly in sumo?

Tags: sumo

When I set a vehicle taking a lane-change maneuver in sumo, I found that the vehicle move to an adjacent lane instantly, which is not similar to human driving. So I tried to use sublane model to improve the vehicle's behavior. I did it by using "lateral-resolution='0.2'" when I define "vType" in ".rou.xml" file. But it didn't work, because the vehicle still moves to an adjacent lane instantly.
So I'm here to ask for help. First, whether it is right to define "lateral-resolution" in vType or not? If it is, why it doesn't work? If not, where to do it? Second, If there are other methods to define a vehicle moving to an adjacent lane constantly instead of instantly?

Answer (score 0):

The vehicle type is not the right place to do it. It is a command line option, so you call `sumo --lateral-resolution 0.2 -c my.sumocfg` or you put it in your sumocfg. The easiest way to achieve continuous lane change is however to use the option `--lanechange.duration` which expects a time value so `sumo --lanechange.duration 2 -c my.sumocfg` sets a duration of 2 seconds for every lane change.